# Is it possible to use the Backspace key in Files 3.6 to return to the previous directory like in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, filemanager

If there is something that I'm really addicted is in pushing the Backspace key every time I want to return to the previous directory in the old file manager (Nautilus), but now with Files I can't do it.

So I'd like to know how to do it on Files, or if there is any plugin that fits my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

BackSpace was used to go to the parent dir. Anyway, in order to restore the Backspace functionality, replace the following line

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "<Alt>Up")
```

with

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")
```

in `~/.config/nautilus/accels`

Answer (score 1):

While Raghunandan solution didn't work for me, I discovered that alt+left arrow does work (and alt+right arrow drills down directories already visited).

I'm also missing the backspace navigation and would be happy to restore it.

Comment: Please use comment section to post result.